# transitionFromView returns false in completion; no transition takes place

Tags: objective-c, uiview, transition

I have a `viewController` and I would like it to switch between `views` depending on a conditional. The `view` I would like to transition to is contained in another `viewController`, but rather than `pushing` to it I would like it to transitioned into. Perhaps this isn't possible, and I have misunderstood what the function does. Here's the code though:

```
 UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MyStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myId"];

    [UIView transitionFromView:self.view toView:viewController.view duration:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        NSLog(@"COMPLETED TRANSITION %d", finished);

        //completion block
    }];
```

The `Log` returns 0 (false) and no transition takes place. Instead the old `view` is shown. I'd be happy to show you more code or give additional information, but I'm not quite sure what's relevant.

Comment: Quick test, and it's working fine for me... on a button-tap in the first view controller. Where are you calling this from?

Comment: In a protocol delegate pattern. If login is successful, a modual viewController is dismissed, and in the viewController the delegate is run and tries to transition the viewController to another viewController.view.

Comment: You need to show at least enough code to make it clear how you are trying to do this. See if you can come up with a [mcve]...